# How to access attributes of a Smartsheet Cell object?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to use the Smartsheet Python SDK to find cells that match a certain `displayValue`. My cells look something like this:

`{"columnId": 6xxxx6xxxx4xxxx8, "displayValue": "John Jacob", "value": "John Jacob"}`

I want to print all cells whose `columnId` == `participantColumnID` AND `displayValue` == `participantNumber`. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to access the Cell attributes and the [API docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#cell-object) don't describe how to access them either. Any help much appreciated.

```
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

participantColumnID = "30xxxxxxxxxx2452"
participantNumber = "12345"

for row in sheet.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        if cell.columnId == participantColumnID:
            if cell.displayValue == participantNumber:
                print(cell)
```

Note that I've also tried accessing via subscript `cell[0]` and `cell[columnId]` and that doesn't work either.  <class 'smartsheet.models.cell.Cell'> is not subscriptable.

`TypeError: 'Cell' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Python or with the Smartsheet Python SDK -- but could your problems be caused by the fact that you're using invalid `Cell` property names in your code?

Seems like [the integration tests (for rows) within the SDK repo in GitHub](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/tests/integration/test_rows.py) shows how to reference `Cell` properties when using the Python SDK. For example, I see this code there (lines 105-108)

```
for row in sheetb.rows:
    ids.append(row.id)
    for cell in row.cells:
        column_ids.append(cell.column_id)
```

Comparing that code with the code you've posted in your question above, one thing that jumps out at me is that you're using `cell.columnId` whereas the integration test uses `cell.column_id`. Likewise, I suspect that where you're using `cell.displayValue` -- it should instead be `cell.display_value`. (See the [definition for the `Cell` object in the SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/smartsheet/models/cell.py) for a complete list of all property names in the `Cell` object.)

Comment: Thanks! That's it. Super helpful.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help!